# Adicionar um limite de "passes" em um slider carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou trabalhando em um simples slider carousel e preciso que quando não existir nenhum ítem anterior ou próximo não seja possível passar para um elemento inexistente como está acontecendo, http://jsfiddle.net/qd5d8x1h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que tenha uma forma mais otimizada, porém funciona perfeitamente.

```
var sliderWidth = 300;
var slider = $('#slider');
var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
var cont =1;

$(document).ready(function() {
var numItems = $('.sliderItem').length;
   $('.date-nav-prev').hide();
});

slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);



$('.date-nav-prev').click(function () { 
    $('#slider').animate({left: '+='+sliderWidth}, 500);
    cont--;
    hidePrev();
    hideNext();
});

$('.date-nav-next').click(function () {
    $('#slider').animate({left: '-='+sliderWidth}, 500);
    cont++;
    hidePrev();
    hideNext();
});


function hideNext(){

if(cont==sliderCount){
        $('.date-nav-next').hide();
    }else{
        $('.date-nav-next').show();
    }
}



function hidePrev(){

    if(cont>1){
        $('.date-nav-prev').show()
    }else{
        $('.date-nav-prev').hide()
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd5d8x1h/7/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<button class="date-nav-prev">< Prev</button>
<button class="date-nav-next">Next ></button>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="sliderItem" id="today">Today's Actions</div>
        <div class="sliderItem" id="today">Today's Actions</div>
        <div class="sliderItem" id="today">Today's Actions</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sliderWidth = 300;
    var slider = $('#slider');
    var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
    var numItems = $('.sliderItem').length;

    if (numItems <= 1) {
        $('.date-nav-prev').hide();
        $('.date-nav-next').hide();
    }

    var numItems = $('.sliderItem').length;
    slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);
    var counter = 0;

    $('.date-nav-prev').click(function () {
        if (counter > 0) {
            counter--;
            $('#slider').animate({ left: '+=' + sliderWidth }, 500);
        }
    });

    $('.date-nav-next').click(function () {
        counter++;
        if (counter < numItems) {
            $('#slider').animate({ left: '-=' + sliderWidth }, 500);
        }
        else {
            counter = 0;
            $('#slider').animate({ left: '+=' + sliderWidth * sliderCount - 150 }, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qd5d8x1h/9/)

Comment: Rafael Barbosa, na verdade o que está acontecendo é que ao clicar no Next até o último elemento está "passando" para um bloco em branco, que não contém nenhum elemento. O que eu preciso é que o botão Next seja disabilitado ao chegar no último elemento do carousel, o mesmo para o botão Prev (Para o primeiro elemento).

Comment: @RaphaelCastro funcionando agora. Quando chega no último elemento ele volta para o primeiro. Se for menor ou igual a 1 ele não aparece o controle. Se estiver no primeiro, ele não volta para o branco.

Answer (score 0):

**Update total:**

Basta controlar o slide atual, e não permitir ir antes de 1 ou depois do numero de slides:

```
var sliderWidth = 300;
var slide = 1;
var slider = $('#slider');
var sliderCount = $('div', slider).length;
slider.width(sliderCount * sliderWidth);

$('.date-nav-prev').click(function () {
    if (slide > 1) {
        slide--;
        slider.animate({ left: '+=' + sliderWidth }, 500);
    }
});

$('.date-nav-next').click(function () {
    if (slide < sliderCount) {
        slide++;
        slider.animate({ left: '-=' + sliderWidth }, 500);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/qd5d8x1h/11/)

Answer (score 0):

Veja se existem elementos irmãos do elemento do slider, ou conte o número de elementos padrão do slider que existem, no caso se for 1 ou menor, voce nao mostra os controles.

Para isso voce poderá usar vários métodos, dois deles utilizam as referencias abaixo, que tem exemplo de uso em cada apontador.

Refs:

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/
- http://api.jquery.com/each/